# docker pull inside docker in a private Hub didn't work

Tags: docker, dockerhub

```
docker pull MyPrivateRepo
```

Works!

but insite a docker container:

```
docker pull MyPrivateRepo
```

Didn't works! (access denied)

the strange thing is that in each case

```
docker pull DockerHub
```

Works!
So basically my private depo or my container don't allow me to pull my private depo...

How is it possible? and How to fix that?

Comment: Probably not so strange. The docker hub certificate is installed per default, your private repo cert is probably not.

Comment: thank you @NielsBechNielsen ! How can I add the private repo cert to my container? :)

Comment: This might help: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/